# "error unparceling Bundle" in SyncAdapter in Lollipop

Tags: android

Since Android 5.0, the below code fails with "error unparcelling Bundle" error.

```
SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
.syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime)
.setSyncAdapter(account, MyContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY).
build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lollipop existence of Bundle is mandatory to build the request. Replace with this code to set the Bundle.

```
SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
.syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime) 
.setSyncAdapter(account, MyContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY)
.setExtras(new Bundle()).
build();
```